Get Content folder path from WebApplication using Console WebJob
How can I access the Content folder of a web application when using a console app? The method
internal static string GetTemplatePath(string fileName)
{
    return Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $@"Content\file.html");
}

returns the bin\debug\ folder of the console app rather than the Content folder of the web application.
Full context: My web job calls a library that references a web application. The GetTemplatePath method provides the path for the web job. When using the web application, it correctly accesses the Content folder.
